# is there any ways to print out every possible integer numbers for dimensions of rectangle/right triangle in a (X x Y) form with their perimeters?

Tags: dimension

eg. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eXTo.png)

requst. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCmxU.png)

I couldn't figure how to start the code. Please help me.

I have to make a Python program which finds rectangles and
right triangles which have integer dimensions, and have a particular
area. my program has to print out a table of all rectangles and right
triangles found which match the given area, with each of their perimeters.

Comment: Hi - please don't link to images. Add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: Yes. Think about the formula for the area of a rectangle and the area of a triangle. The other trick is to require Y <= X to avoid duplicate finds.